# Yet another "Computer won't boot from Ubuntu Install Media" question

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb, cd-drive

I've been banging my head against a wall.  I have an older machine with a Gigabyte P35-DS3L motherboard.  For some reason it'll boot other installs from USB and CD/DVD-ROM, but not Ubuntu.  (Tried from both USB and CD/DVD-ROM with same results.)  It just hangs shortly after POST after detecting PCI devices, the last thing in the list is ACPI.  Normally after that it would say something about DMI pool, but it just hangs there before the DMI pool thing.  I understand this is anecdotal, just offering as a frame of reference were the boot process hangs.

It'll boot windows 7 installer from usb along with several other random "start-up" utilities but not Ubuntu.

I've also confirmed that the same USB sticks (I've tried several) do work in my other machines.  The other PC's boot from the Ubuntu USB media just fine, so I know the MBR and boot "stuff" is there and working.  One such machine is also an older Gigabyte UD3P based board.  Another machine is a much newer UEFI based ASrock Ext3Gen3 board.  Just won't work on the DS3L for some reason?

I've spent many hours pouring over BIOS settings, using F12 boot menu, trying different methods of creating the bootable usb sticks (both unetbootin and universal USB installer, etc etc...)  Also have tried re-downloading the iso files several times, all of which worked fine on the other machines.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest disconnecting all non essential hardware. I once had a problem where I couldn't get an OS to install on a computer (The installation process would crash) just because it didn't like my card reader being connected during the install process. Alternatively you could always try putting your hard drive into another computer (since you mentioned having others), install ubuntu, and then put the hard drive back.

Comment: I'm embarrassed I hadn't thought of installing with another machine...  Excellent tip and one I will try, thanks!  As far as unplugging non-essentials, I tried that.  Along with just about everything else I could think of.  (Except the obvious:  To simply install w/ another machine and transfer the drive back.)